# PHP echo works on Page A but not on Page B

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

My goal is to populate a hidden form field with the utm_source from url.

Basically this:

```
<input id="fieldihhdji" name="cm-f-ihhdji" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET["utm_source"] ?>" />
```

The problem is this form works perfectly on one page, but not on another.

Working: [museumhack.com/test-a/?utm_source=hello](http://museumhack.com/test-a/?utm_source=hello) (form field is hidden, but populates value)

Not working: [museumhack.com/test-b/?utm_source=hello](http://museumhack.com/test-b/?utm_source=hello) (at the bottom)

It seems like the pages may be processing the double quotes differently, but not clear how to fix. Wordpress required a plugin to process on page PHP -- I installed that and don't think it's the problem.

Here is the entire form that I copy/pasted between pages:

```
<form action="http://museumhack.createsend.com/t/d/s/ihhykl/" method="post" id="lead-capture">
<p>
    <input id="fieldName" name="cm-name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name"/>
</p>
<p>
    <input id="fieldEmail" name="cm-ihhykl-ihhykl" type="email" placeholder="you@email.com" required />
</p>
<p>
    <input id="fieldjuuilj" name="cm-f-juuilj" type="text" placeholder="(212)555-5555" />
</p>
<p>
    <input id="fieldihhdji" name="cm-f-ihhdji" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET["utm_source"] ?>" />
</p>
<p>
    <button type="submit">Request Quick Quote</button>
</p>
```

Thanks,

Comment: One of your tag star/ends was pasted as an HTML entity, or is being converted into one - http://puu.sh/ohY3N/aec9a5028a.png

Comment: on page B php is not executed https://i.gyazo.com/f50fac023c9b88f9fcb4ba6fef1407c0.png

Comment: change the double quotes of the $_GET property into single quotes. A PHP command should also end with a `;`.

Comment: also you can write `value="<?php =$_GET["utm_source"] ?>` instead of echo

Comment: I changed to single quotes -- but there still seems to be an issue closing out the PHP, i.e., the submit button disappears, inspecting the element shows the different style of double quote? i.e., curly vs. straight

    <input id="fieldihhdji" name="cm-f-ihhdji" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['utm_source']; ?>” />
    </p>
<p>
        <button type=" submit"="">

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code , this might help you

```
<input id="fieldihhdji" name="cm-f-ihhdji" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['utm_source']='';?>">
```